# Google Chrome Extension - click button within class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will imitate a button click on a tab.  I know the button is within a class "player-play"...here is the structure of the class and child elements.

```
div class: player-play
   table
     tbody
        tr
          td
            em
              button (here's want I want to *click*)
```

The button has an ID but it is not static...however, this is the only button within my "player-play" class.  I attempted to use this code

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabid, {action: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\").click();"}, function(response){});
```

but that doesn't work.

*Just as a side note, I've tried debugging page to get the elements within the page but the debugger is seeing "document" as my debug page and not the tab I am debugging...any ideas on how to specify what "document" should be?*

So is there any way that I can use click() based on a type and my known class?

Just for overall reference, I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut extension that would allow me to play/pause my Synology AudioStation web app (provided it is open in one of my tabs).  I used [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rdio-hotkeys/lbnmcjfhalmlhpfcaedfoaikgekgpmhe?hl=en) extension for reference (as I said I am a noob at Javascript and documentation seems to be scattered)

Full Code:

```
var currentRdioTabID = 0;
//update current tab
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){

});


//to respond to new key press system
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){
    chrome.tabs.query({
            url : "[url here]"
        },
        function(tabs){

            if(tabs.length == 0){
                console.log('no tabs found.');
            }else if(tabs.length >= 1){
                thetab = tabs[0];
                //if(tabs.length == 1){
                    thetab = tabs[0];
                    console.log('found one tab');
                /*}else{
                    //console.log('found mo tabs');
                    for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {masterCheck:true}, function(response){
                            //console.log(response);
                            if(response.masterCheck == 'true'){
                                thetab = tabs[i];
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }*/
                switch(command){
                    case "prev":
                        //console.log('playpause');
                        //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(thetab.id, {action:"R.player.playPause();"}, function(response){});
                        console.log('play-pause');
                        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(thetab.id, {action: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\");"}, function(response){});
                        //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(thetab.id, {action: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\").click();"}, function(response){});
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(thetab.id, {code: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\").click();"}, function(response){});
                        var t = document.getElementsByClassName('player-play');
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(thetab.id, {action: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\");"}, function(response){rr});
                        break;
                    // case "next":
                    //  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(thetab.id, {action:"R.player.next();"}, function(response){});
                    //  break;
                    // case "prev":
                    //  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(thetab.id, {action:"R.player.previous();"}, function(response){});
                    //  break;
                    case "focus":
                        console.log('changing tabs')
                        chrome.tabs.update(thetab.id, {active:true});
                        break;
                }                   
            }
        }

    );
});
```

Comment: Change `sendMessage` to `executeScript`, and `action` to `code`. Also, show us how you are triggering the code fragment you included.

Comment: Tried this 'chrome.tabs.executeScript(thetab.id, {code: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"player-play\").click();"}, function(response){});' and no luck.  Updated original question with full code.